# How to terminate a process in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I've started a process through system.diagnostics .process.start("C:/process.exe")
Now my question is, how can I terminate the same process in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://vbnetsample.blogspot.com/2007/08/start-and-kill-process.html

Answer (score 2):

The Start() method returns a Process object.  Call its Kill method:

```
  Private WithEvents MyProcess As Process

  Private Sub MyProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyProcess.Exited
    MyProcess = Nothing
  End Sub

  Private Sub RunIt()
    MyProcess = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
  End Sub

  Private Sub StopIt()
    If MyProcess IsNot Nothing Then MyProcess.Kill()
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dim myProc as Process
myProc=Process.Start("C:\Process.exe")

...
myProc.kill
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned the Kill method to force a process to terminate.  You might wish to call CloseMainWindow so that the app can have a chance to shut down gracefully.